# What is the proper way to apply aria-live/aria-relevant to an Angular data binding?

Tags: html, angular, wai-aria

Let's say I have an element with bindings in an Angular template like so,

```
<div role="region" aria-live="polite">
    <div aria-relevant="?">
        {{ someVariable }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ someOtherVariable }}
    </div>
    <!-- more dynamic content below -->
</div>
```

The parent div has `aria-live=polite` so that screen readers know the child elements will update their content. The div has multiple children that all update their content based on the value of different variables. I want to ensure the indicated child div (the first one) is read through screen reader when it updates, and not the others. My question is what value of *aria-relevant* should be used in the child div? Acccording to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-relevant), the options are `additions`,`removals`,`text`. It is my understanding that `additions` implies elements underneath the parent are added to the DOM, `removal` means elements are removed from the DOM and `text` means the text is removed or added,

I am unsure what exactly goes on under the hood when Angular binds to the template with {{}}. Does it actually remove the child element from the DOM and replace it with another? Or does it update the content of the child element? From the perspective of the screen reader, is there any difference between the two operations?

Comment: From my experience, Angular only updates the value in that position of the HTML. The two options you presented would not have any difference for the person reading, as the content is being updated either way.

Comment: If it's only updating the inner HTML, how do you inform the screen reader that it needs to re-read the updated content?

Comment: It depends of what tipe of update, if you add things, you use additions and so on... I found w3 org page were the use of aria-love and aria-relevant is explained in more detail: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ensure the indicated child div (the first one) is read through screen reader when it updates, **and not the others**.

Child elements that should **not** be announced really shouldn't be children of the live region.  There isn't a *"none"* value for `aria-relevant`.  I suppose if you used *"removals"* and then never removed any DOM elements from the child and only updated the text of the child, then nothing would be announced.

For child elements that **should** announce something, I have never tried setting `aria-relevant` or `aria-atomic` on the child element.  I always have the element with `aria-live` also have `aria-relevant` or `aria-atomic`.

Comment: Allow me to clarify. Some of the child elements are graphics without any text that change their src dynamically in addition to the div with the dynamic text. I suppose the imgs have alt attributes that update, though, so I guess it would make sense to announce those updates as well.

Comment: Even in that case, I wouldn't want the graphics (svgs?) embedded in a live region.  If you want to update the user about what changed in the graphic, usually a text description is better and **that** could be in the live region.